# How to avoid IntelliJ to reset language level?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-10, javacompiler

I am having troubles with this which have been answered dusin of times on this site.

My take on the problem is a bit different. I have a project which builds fine using maven 3.5.x and java release 10 (configured in the maven-compiler-plugin)
When looking in IntelliJ's project structure, all modules have language level 10 (but the projects settings is language level 6 and the chosen sdk in the project structure is 1.8...

However, even if I change the sdk to java 10 and the projects language level to 10, the error pasted below still occurs... ????

My IntelliJ version: IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.5

To reproduce this error:

- Check out from version control (GIT)
- GitHub: https://github.com/jactor-rises/jactor-rises.git

  Try to build it within IntelliJ:

> Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module
> 'jactor-commons' Information:javac 10.0.1 was used to compile java
> sources Information:29/10/2018, 21:31 - Compilation completed with 1
> error and 0 warnings in 4 s 777 ms Error:java: release version 5 not
> supported

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can update the Java Compiler version of your module to be executed to use Java version 10 with the following settings :

***Build, Execution, Deployment => Compiler => Java Compiler => Update Target Bytecode version***

[image]

In the image above you can notice that the modules *guice* and *hbase* are defaulting to use Java version 5 while I've updated the others to use Java version 11 which is when compiling and executing them with JDK 11 works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had to update value in `pom.xml` & refreshing maven.

```xml
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: maven.compiler.source and maven.compiler.target has been deprecated... use <release>11</release>

Comment: refreshing maven was what missing in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just update the `pom.xml` and it works for me.

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.11</source>
        <target>1.11</target>
        <release>11</release>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```