# problem in compile time when using "var" in jdk 11

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-11

when I use the word "var" the IDE recognize the command, but when I compile the code, it gives me an error:

> Error:(10, 17) java: cannot find symbol
>
> symbol:   class var
>
> location: class Exp

the code:

```
public final class Exp
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        var x=5;
    }
}
```

So why does it happen? How can i solve it?

the pics:
[image: the project SDK is 11 and so is the language level]

[image: The module language level is 11 also]

[image: The full warning]

Comment: Have you properly set IntelliJ?

Comment: Are you sure you are using JDK 10 / 11 for compilation?

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the Intellij project configs ... or Maven / Gradle / whatever build configs ... are not selecting Java 11 as your source level; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915259/how-to-change-project-language-level-for-all-project-in-intellij

Comment: My project language level is 11 and i'm using JDK 11
in the build output is says:
> Information:javac 11.0.1 was used to compile java sources

Comment: Well clearly the compiler you are actually using *thinks* that the source level is 9 or less.  Otherwise it would realize that `var` in that context is not a class name.   Did you check **all** of the things I suggested?

Comment: Yes.. if you want you can check it yourself somehow.. can I upload some screenshots to this conversation?

Comment: No ... I don't.  I trust you have checked it yourself properly.  (And it is no skin off my nose if you didn't :-) )

Comment: Additionally, to note, you might be compiling with javac from JDK 11 but executing with java from JDK of version lower than 10, since the error reads `Error:(10, 17)` **`java`** `: cannot find symbol`

Comment: Are you using Maven? If not, navigate to `Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment, ->Compiler->Java Compiler` and see if you have a module that has a lower target bytecode version, although that doesn't seem to pose a problem for `var`. Alternatively, check if your **module** language level is set to 11 under `Project Structure->Project Settings->Modules->Language Level`.

Comment: I've edited the post and added some images for explanation..

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Thanks to @Marv the solution was

> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler

and raise the Project Bytecode version to 11. (I raised it from 8 to 11)

Pic:
[image: Go to Project bytecode version and raise it to max level]

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53053587/how-to-avoid-intellij-to-reset-language-level