# Cannot resolve symbol 'var' in intellij, cannot fix through byteversion

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am having trouble with my application. Whenever I try to use the character 'var' it is not recognized by the IDE. I tried [this thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53140625/problem-in-compile-time-when-using-var-in-jdk-11) but it did not change my problem.

I made a method for retrieving users from a database by using a UserRepository and that is where the problem takes place:

```
    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {

        var users = (List<User>) userRepository.findAll();

//        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>(userRepository.findAll());

        return users;
    }
```

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCqON.png)

Any tips?

Comment: You need to use Java 11 in the project structure (Language Level). Check that.

Comment: the "Local Variable Type Inference" (i.e. var) has been introduced since Java 10, thus you need to use a JDK 10+ version.

Comment: Please read: ["Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- Please [edit] the question and add the compilation error, as well as the definition of `userRepository::findAll`.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I went into File > Project Structure > Modules and changed the language level of my project to 11. Now 'var' is recognised. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Let's put everything in the answer, so other people can be helped by this. Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Local Variable Type Inference" (i.e. var) has been introduced since Java 10, thus you need to use a JDK 10+ version.
If you don't have such a version, please download it by Oracle website and install it, then launch IntelliJ and go to "File->Project Settings->Project" and select the JDK version in "Project JDK" field.

Answer (score 0):

JDK version wrong.
You should JDK 10+ in this idea project setting.